# CountDownTimer inside Service stopped after application killed - Android

Tags: android, android-service, countdowntimer, android-broadcastreceiver

I'm new to services and BroadcastReceiver so maybe this question is newbie, but I didn't found the solution for my question after a long search on the web.

I need to run a CountDownTimer inside service, so the time keep moving even the application was finished.

In my code I based on [THIS EXAMPLE.](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/10/use-broadcast-receiver-background-services-android/)

My code works fine, but after the application is finished the CountDownTimer stopped(The service doesn't destroyed, just the timer).

I tried to implement it in different ways, but nothing works for me.

This is the part of my code that relevant:

**AlarmReciver**:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent background = new Intent(context, BackgroundService.class);
        Bundle bundle =  intent.getExtras();

        background.putExtra("time", bundle.getInt("time"));
        context.startService(background);
    }
}
```

**BackgroundService** :

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {

    private final static String TAG = "BroadcastService";

    private CountDownTimer cdt = null;
    private Bundle bundle;
    private boolean isRunning;
    private Context context;
    private int timeInMili;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
         this.context = this;
         this.isRunning = false;

    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() { 
        //cdt.cancel();
        Log.i(TAG, "Timer cancelled");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        bundle =  intent.getExtras();
        timeInMili = bundle.getInt("time");

         if(!this.isRunning) {
             this.isRunning = true;
         }

         cdt = new CountDownTimer(timeInMili, 1000) {
             @Override
             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                 Log.i(TAG, "Countdown seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

             }

             @Override
             public void onFinish() {

                 Log.i(TAG, "Timer finished");
                 stopSelf();
             }
         };
         cdt.start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity** (extends FragmentActivity):

```
public void StartBackgroundAlarm(int timeInMili)
    {

         Intent alarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
         alarm.putExtra("time", timeInMili);
         PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarm, 0);
         AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), pendingIntent);

    }
```

**MANIFEST** :

```
 <service android:enabled="true" android:name= "com.MES.yo.servicemanager.BackgroundService" />
 <receiver android:name="com.MES.yo.servicemanager.AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
```

Comment: Start your service as foreground service

Comment: But, if I start the service on the foreground, is it still work when the application will close
?

Comment: Ok I tried but it doesn't work. it's acting the same

Comment: Then you are doing it won't give me some time I'll share the code

Comment: Hey try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/34855177/1752366